# Google compute engine not initialized on new project

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have started a new project on google cloud but I am unable to use the compute engine. I'm getting the following message even after 6-7 hours.

> Error Google Compute Engine is not ready for use yet in the project.
>   It may take several minutes if Google Compute Engine has just been
>   enabled, or if this is the first time you use Google Compute Engine in
>   the project.

Is there something I am missing or there is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the project and created a new and it worked. Also the old one is stuck on pending deletion.

If someone from google wants to take a look, it would be nice to inform me on what happened.

Answer (score 0):

When [projects are deleted](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#managingprojects), it take a few days before the project is permanently deleted. About what happened, it could be that when the project was created the project wasn't provisioned correctly, causing this issue, but you solved it by creating a new project.